# Using bytearray.translate() with a table

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, byte, translate

I'm trying to remove certain characters from a bytearray (specifically, certain control characters that are messing up my formatting)

I manually listed individual translates and it worked, but **can I format this as a single translate?**
In the string variant, the input can be a dictionary table. But I get an error when I tried this that parameters must be a bytearray object.

```
translation_table_0A = bytes.maketrans(b"\x0A", b"\x00")
translation_table_0B = bytes.maketrans(b"\x0B", b"\x00")
translation_table_0C = bytes.maketrans(b"\x0C", b"\x00")
translation_table_0D = bytes.maketrans(b"\x0D", b"\x00")
translation_table_04 = bytes.maketrans(b"\x04", b"\x00")

test_bytes = bytearray(b"\x75\x66\x73\x62\x0D\x73\x62\x0B\x00\x74\xF1\x74\x73\x62\x61\x76\x00\x0C\x76\x02\x04\x01\x62\x68\x72\x74\x00\x00\x00\x0A\x01\x00")

out_list = test_bytes.translate(translation_table_0A)  # remove \x0A
out_list = out_list.translate(translation_table_0B)  # remove \x0B
out_list = out_list.translate(translation_table_0C)  # remove \x0C
out_list = out_list.translate(translation_table_0D)  # remove \x0D
out_list = out_list.translate(translation_table_04)  # remove \x04

print(f"Output coded: {obj}")
print(f"Output decoded: {obj.decode('mac-roman')}")
```

I would think it would work like this:

```
translate_dict = {b"\x0A" : b"\x00", b"\x0B" : b"\x00", b"\x0C" : b"\x00", b"\x0D" : b"\x00", b"\x04" : b"\x00", }

out_list = test_bytes.translate(translate_dict)  # remove Control Chars
```

But it doesn't. Does anyone know how to get this working?

Unfortunately the documentation is lacking in details:
[bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes)
[bytes maketrans()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.maketrans)
[bytes methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-methods)
[bytes translate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.translate)

From the maketrans method, a table can be generated, but 'from' and 'to' must be byte-like objects, so tuples, lists, or dictionaries wont work.

note: Not interested in regex solutions, or other libraries. Specifically looking for this application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a `bytes` translation table, you get a 256-byte mapping of bytes, that is indexed into by the source byte value, and returns the *n*th byte value in the mapping. You don't have to set up 4 different translation tables to translate 4 bytes, you can do it like this:

```
>>> translation_table = bytes.maketrans(b"\x0A\x0B\x0C\x0D\x04", b"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00")
```

That will let you change the unwanted byte values to `\x00` like this:

```
>>> test_bytes=bytearray(b"\x75\x66\x73\x62\x0D\x73\x62\x0B\x00\x74\xF1\x74\x73\x62\x61\x76\x00\x0C\x76\x02\x04\x01\x62\x68\x72\x74\x00\x00\x00\x0A\x01\x00")
>>> test_bytes.translate(translation_table)    
bytearray (b'ufsb\x00sb\x00\x00t\xf1tsbav\x00\x00v\x02\x00\x01bhrt\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00')
```

which does not look exactly like `test_bytes` with 4 byte values changed, because the default representation of a printable character in a bytestring is the printable character and not the hex escape. You can see this if you ask for `test_bytes` back:

```
>>> test_bytes
bytearray (b'ufsb\rsb\x0b\x00t\xf1tsbav\x00\x0cv\x02\x04\x01bhrt\x00\x00\x00\n\x01\x00')
```

Here sequences such as `tsbav` and `bhrt` appear as printable characters and not as hex escapes. But it is only the representation that differs.

If you are working with `bytes`, you can't use a dictionary as a translation table. In Python 3, where strings are Unicode, a 256-byte mapping table won't work, because there are 1,114,112 possible codepoints that the table might need to translate. So for strings, `translate()` uses a `dict` instead. While efficient, a `dict` can't match a 256-byte character map for efficiency. So `bytes.maketrans()` makes a 256-byte character map, but `str.maketrans()` makes a `dict`, and the corresponding `translate()` methods expect the corresponding kind of translation table.

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I couldn't figure out. This just makes my code so much cleaner and efficient. Thank you.